# Match regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Can someone help me to match the pattern? I need to get numbers out of this string

```
TASK REMAINING TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [1.5], TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [5.0], PLAN ESTIMATE added [5.0 Points]
```

I need to get exactly the numbers after TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL. So, it should be in regex, but not in the match.

Comment: Is there not a nice API for accessing this data? Why are you screen-scraping this tool? (Rally? FogBugz?)

Comment: @Phrogz It's rally. And the API gives you revisions in this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex would get the numbers for you:

```
/\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]/
```

1. Finds an opening bracket
2. Captures 1 or more digits
3. If there's a dot it must be followed by 1 or more digits and captures this aswell
4. Finds the closing brackets

---

Update:

```
TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from \[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\] to \[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]
```

The first number will be stored in group1 and the second in group2.

```
s = "TASK REMAINING TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [1.5], TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [5.0], PLAN ESTIMATE added [5.0 Points]"
pattern = /TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from \[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\] to \[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]/

if s =~ pattern
   print "value1 = ", $1, ", value2 = ", $2
end
```

Output:

```
value1 = 0.0, value2 = 5.0
```

See it in action here: http://codepad.org/mYARv7Zr

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I must use look behind. Why is it working, can you explain?

Comment: One could use a look behind to solve this problem also but this is much simpler than that. It simply check character by character from left to right without capturing anything. When it finds a opening bracket i captures the contained digits inside, then moves on to the next bracket.

Comment: Thank for a help. I just familiar with the case, when engine matches everything regex contains. Thanks again!

Comment: Just ftr, ruby has had look around since 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = "TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [5.0]"
s.scan(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)
#=> ["0.0", "0.5"]
```

If you need the floats you can add

```
.map(&:to_f)
```

Comment: Maybe you should change the expression to `/\d+(\.\d+)?/` because the current one might accept nonsense like `5..2..3.2.1`. (Unlikely, maybe, but still, there's no context.)

Comment: Just wrap with if s.include?('TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL')

Comment: It will not work. Example is "TASK REMAINING TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [1.5], TASK ESTIMATE TOTAL changed from [0.0] to [5.0], PLAN ESTIMATE added [5.0 Points]"

Comment: I'm pretty unclear about what you want. So in all three cases you want the number values matched? What is the criteria for the part in capitals? Or are you just saying you want any number contained in square brackets matched?

Answer (score 0):

Regexp

```
\[([\d\.]+)\]
```

in ruby

```
string.match(/\[([\d\.]+)\]/)
```